# tableau iframe call prompts login

Tags: authentication, iframe, tableau-api, trusted

I am using tableau trusted ticket call to show a report embeded in my site.
I formed a url and when I call it in browser tab, reports correctly loads but when I call it in iframe it prompts with tableau login screen.

third-party cookies are enabled in the browser.

anything am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Sign in to Tableau Server through Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804090/auto-sign-in-to-tableau-server-through-iframe)

Comment: I tried trusted ticket but on iframe call it promts login